# Query not accessing a Room database using DAO, no errors

Tags: java, android, android-room, dao

Hey I'm new to Android and still learning. Im doing a project for the university.
What im trying to do is a login/register system using Room. 
Register page works fine, generates the database and includes any new users. My problem is when im checking for an existing user on the login page. 
After pressing the login button the app just kind of stops working if it has to perform a query. Profiler says that the app is crashed even though i can still navigate it.
 
I have no Errors in logcat or Run. Please tell me what am i doing wrong when accessing the database. If i could see at least one error i would have been able to solve the problem.

Here are the java files

### RegisterActivity.java

```
package com.example.spacetrt40;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.spacetrt40.EntityClass.UserModel;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText  name,phone,password,email;
    Button save,getData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        name=findViewById(R.id.etName);
        email=findViewById(R.id.etMail);
        phone=findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
        password=findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        save=findViewById(R.id.btnReg2);
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendData();
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendData() {
        String name_txt = name.getText().toString().trim();
        String phone_txt = phone.getText().toString().trim();
        String email_txt = email.getText().toString().trim();
        String password_txt = password.getText().toString().trim();
        UserModel model = new UserModel();
        model.setName(name_txt);
        model.setEmail(email_txt);
        model.setPassword(password_txt);
        model.setPhone(phone_txt);
        DatabaseClass.getDatabase(getApplicationContext()).getDao().insertAllData(model);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Data Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    }
```

### DatabaseClass.java

```
package com.example.spacetrt40;


import android.content.Context;

import androidx.room.Database;
import androidx.room.Room;
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;

import com.example.spacetrt40.EntityClass.UserModel;

@Database(entities = {UserModel.class}, version = 1,exportSchema = false)
public abstract class DatabaseClass extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract DaoClass getDao();

    private static DatabaseClass instance;



    static DatabaseClass getDatabase(final Context context){
        if (instance==null){
            synchronized (DatabaseClass.class){
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context, DatabaseClass.class, "DATABASE").allowMainThreadQueries().fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build();


            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

}
```

### UserModel.java

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.room.ColumnInfo;
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

@Entity(tableName = "user")
public class UserModel {

    public void setKey(int key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @NonNull

    private int key;


    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    private String name;



    @ColumnInfo(name = "email")
    private String email;



    @ColumnInfo(name = "phone")
    private String phone;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "password")
    private String password;

    public int getKey() {
        return key;
    }


    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;

    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }



    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

### DaoClass.java

```
package com.example.spacetrt40;


import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.Query;

import com.example.spacetrt40.EntityClass.UserModel;

import java.util.List;

@Dao
public interface DaoClass {

    @Insert
    void insertAllData(UserModel model);
    //Select All Data
    @Query("select * from  user")
    List<UserModel> getAllData();


    @Query("SELECT * from user where email=(:email) and password=(:password)")
    UserModel login(String email,String password);



}
```

### LoginActivity.java

```
package com.example.spacetrt40;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.spacetrt40.EntityClass.UserModel;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        EditText user = findViewById(R.id.etUser);
        EditText password = findViewById(R.id.etPass);
        Button login = findViewById(R.id.button3);





        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String emailText = user.getText().toString();
                String passwordText=password.getText().toString();
                if (emailText.isEmpty()||passwordText.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Fill in all Fields",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }else{
                    //perform query
                    DatabaseClass userDatabase = DatabaseClass.getDatabase(getApplicationContext());
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            DaoClass daoClass = userDatabase.getDao();
                            new Thread((new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    UserModel userModel= daoClass.login(emailText,passwordText);
                                    if (userModel==null){
                                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid Credentials",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }else{
                                        Intent in=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(in);


                                    }
                                }
                            }));
                        }
                    }).start();
                }

            }
        });
    }





    public void sendToReg(View v){
        Button reg = findViewById(R.id.btnReg);
        Intent in = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }

}
```

I will provide any other Information if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your current issue is that you are trying to run a runnable inside a runnable without starting the inner runnable.

The query is fine except that there is no need for the parenthesises around the arguments (email and password). The following would be fine:-

```
@Query("SELECT * from user where email=:email and password=:password")
UserModel login(String email,String password);
```

In regard to the current issue you may find that using the following for the **login** button's **onClickListener** in the **LoginActivity** moves you on :-

```
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String emailText = user.getText().toString();
            String passwordText=password.getText().toString();
            if (emailText.isEmpty()||passwordText.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Fill in all Fields",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }else{
                //perform query
                DatabaseClass userDatabase = DatabaseClass.getDatabase(getApplicationContext());
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        DaoClass daoClass = userDatabase.getDao();
                        UserModel userModel= daoClass.login(emailText,passwordText);
                        if (userModel==null){
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid Credentials",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }else{
                            Intent in=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(in);
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        }
    });
```

i.e. just the single runnable.

Comment: This indeed solved my problem, Thank you.

Comment: @spaceTRT that's good. If you believe that the answer helped you and is the best answer given then you could consider ticking the Answer as the Answer. This way the Question and the Answer become more prominent and potentially more helpful.